# Partial dconf dump with full paths

Tags: dconf

Custom system-wide default `dconf` settings [can be set](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-custom-defaults.html.en) with a keyfile in `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/`. The file must contain keys with their full path in this case.

`dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ > org.cinnamon.dconf` allows exporting keys. The output file contains keys with their relative path though.

How can I dump *partial* `dconf` configuration with full paths so that it is in the format suitable for the system-wide keyfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ | sed "s~^\[~&org/cinnamon/~;/^\[/s~//\]$~\]~" > org.cinnamon.dconf
```

**Explanation**

The `sed` command first searches output for strings starting from the square bracket (`[`) and adds the target path after the bracket, then it again searches for strings starting from the square bracket and removes any occurance of double slashes in the end of the path. The additional search is required, because descendant categories in the output are printed without leading/trailing slashes; but the target category itself (`/org/cinnamon/` in this case) is printed as `/`.